# HibernateUtil issues with annotated classes

Tags: java, hibernate

In my project i am not using hibernate.cfg.xml, instead i am using

HibernateUtil class that i configured like this :

```
public class HibernateUtil {
private static SessionFactory sessionFactory  ;
static {
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration();

    configuration.addAnnotatedClass (Model.User.class);
    configuration.addAnnotatedClass (Model.CarInfo.class);
    configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class","com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test");
    configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", "root");
    configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", "");
    configuration.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
    configuration.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
    configuration.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
    configuration.setProperty(" hibernate.connection.pool_size", "50");

    StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties());

    sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(builder.build());

}
public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
}
}
```

And all crud operations work, but there is a big problem, for some reason, this two different tables, share same id counter, that is :
i add user and user gets id of 1 no problem there!

then i try to add car_info and car_id should be 1, but its 2, if i go back and add new user he has id of 3.
I dont understand for the love of god why this happens.

I assume that my HibernatUtil class is making this issue, but i am not sure why.
this is car class that has primitive fields

```
 @Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="car_id")
private int car_id;
```

and this is other class that has property fields,

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
public class User

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "id")
public int getId() {
    return id.get();
}
```

Again CRUD operations work on both flowlesly, i just do not understand why hibernate shares id counter for two different tables

Comment: hi , i would like to suggest you to explore more on this property "hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings" , which is required to generate new  mappings .

Comment: I am not sure i fully understand you, i used this type of annotation for my classes before, there should be no problems(as a matter of fact i have spring application that uses same annotations, and it generationtype is auto, and still different tables get different ids generated), there for i think problem is either in hibernate util not properly configured, or the fact i use different annotations styles in models.

Comment: when i was going through i seen that while using annotation we may need to change it from default type  sequence to auto generated as true . Good 2 see that you are able to get solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so i found out what was causing the problem :

using

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
```

means that hibernate will use default strategy defined in database, which most of the time is IDENTITY, however in my case, setting generation type to auto was choosing SEQUENCE generation type.

so i had two possible solutions, using

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
```

or

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="pk_gen")
@SequenceGenerator(name="pk_gen", sequenceName="p_seq", allocationSize=1)
```

now i do not know what is the cause of this, perhaps mysql changed something in newer versions 5.7.17 is the one i use.
and version of hibernate is 5.2.6.

Hope this will help someone else too.

Cheers